# Is the robe that Jesus wears "Dipped" or "Spattered" in blood

Tags: revelation, isaiah

In Revelation 19:13, regarding the rider on the white horse, it is written (NIV),

> He is dressed in a **robe dipped in blood.**

In the same chapter at verse 15 it is written,

> **He treads the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God almighty.**

I understand that verse  15 is a reference to Isaiah 63:1-3 where it is written,

> 63:1 **Who is this ,robed in splendour,**
>
> striding forward in the greatness of his strength?

63:2-3,

> **2** Why are your garments red,
>
> **like those of one treading the winepress?**
>
> **3** I have trodden the winepress alone;
>
> from the nations no-one was with me.
>
> I trampled them in my anger
>
> and trod them down in my wrath;
>
> **their blood spattered my garments**,
>
> and stained all my clothing.

My question is,

Is the robe that has been "dipped" in blood in Rev 19:13,the same robe that is being referred to in Isaiah.
My reason for asking is because Isaiah says "spattered in blood," but Revelation says "dipped in blood."
My understanding is that the word "spattered" means to sprinkle,and the word "dipped" means to immerse.

> **Bapto** to dip, dip in, immerse to dip into dye, to dye, colour Not to
>   be confused with 907, baptizo. The clearest example that showsthe
>   meaning of baptizo is a text from the Greek poet and
>   physician Nicander, who lived about 200 B.C. It is a recipe for making
>   pickles and is helpful because it uses both words. Nicander says that
>   in order to make a pickle, the vegetable should first be
>   **'dipped'(bapto)** into boiling water and then **'baptised' (baptizo)** in
>   the vinegar solution. Both verbs concern the immersing of vegetables in
>   a solution. But the first is temporary. The second, the act of baptising
>   the vegetable, produces a permanent change. Lexicons - New Testament
>   Greek Lexicon - New Testament Greek Lexicon - King James Version -

In Genesis 37:31 the word "dipped" is used to describe the actions of the brothers of Joseph when they dipped his robe in goats blood.

> "Then they got Joseph's robe, slaughtered a goat and dipped the robe
>   in the blood."

Comment: Hello, again! I'm not questioning the rendering of the word "bapto" as being "immersed" vs "sprinkled", but I am questioning "who's" blood in the Revelations account it is dipped. Since the account is "figurative", everything up to this point in Rev. is synonymous with "righteousness", and the Rider(Christ) is wearing a robe dipped in "righteous blood"(all those behind Him are righteous". This is opposed to the "unrighteous blood" of His enemies(Remember: the "Beast" is a red-colored dragon)(Rev. 12:3). This is who He makes war against and destroys.

Comment: @ user2479, could be dipped in "goats blood," if you choose to navigate by the sun,the moon and the stars for interpretation. http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+25:31-46

Comment: The point, in essence is that this account is "figurative" and not "Literal"; therefore the 'horses, colors, names, crowns are representative of another reality, and not the reality in itself. On another answer, I posted, "If you can capture the scene on your Nikon and reproduce the image on a photograph-the Context is Literal." If you want to make a comparison w/ the Isaiah passage-"No man was with Me", therefore, the other riders behind the "King of Kings and Lord of Lords, will have to all turn around and go back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we compare the Isaiah passage from the LXX with the passage in The Revelation, the idea appears as soaking. That is, the vestments are soaked with blood (which comes from dipping).

> [**Isaiah 63:2-3**](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/33-esaias-nets.pdf) (NETS)
>   <sup>2</sup> “Why are your garments red,
>   and your clothes as if from a trodden wine press?”
>   <sup>3</sup> “*I am* full of a trampled *wine press*,
>   and of the nations no man is with me,
>   and I trampled them in wrath
>   and crushed them like earth
>   and brought down their blood to the earth.

The initial words of verse 3 are "πλήρης καταπεπατημένης" which is the nominative singular predicate adjective, [πλήρης](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G4134&t=NASB)  (*I am* full) combined with the genitive singular present middle participle, [καταπεπατημένης](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G2662&t=NASB) (of a trampled *winepress*). That is, the word winepress does not occur in this verse, but is understood as the referent, since the last feminine noun (in the genitive singular) was the last word of the preceding verse, *i.e*., "winepress." Therefore the vestments are "full" or, better, ***saturated*** with what was trampled.

So, in summary, the imagery of The Revelation carries the imagery more consistent with the LXX, where the vestments are not just "splattered," but soaked in blood.

Thus the participle in [Revelation 19:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2019:13%20&version=NASB) ([βάπτω](http://www.blueletterbible.org/LANG/LEXICON/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G911&t=NASB)), which is in the perfect passive accusative, brings the idea of soaking in liquid. The same meaning of the same verb appears when Lazarus was to dip his finger in water ([Lk 16:24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lk%2016:24&version=NASB)), or Jesus was going to dip his morsel of bread to indicate the person by whom he was to be betrayed ([Jn 13:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jn%2013:26&version=NASB)). In both of these cases, something is immersed in liquid, and gets wet. Also please click [**here**](http://www.obohu.cz/bible/index.php?styl=LXXK&styl_hled=ASV&k=2S&kap=1&ret=G911&typ=1&omezeni=cela_bible&hled=adv&advsearch=Find) to see every instance in the LXX where the Greek word [βάπτω](http://www.blueletterbible.org/LANG/LEXICON/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G911&t=NASB) occurs. Please note that in each instance, something gets wet by some degree of immersion in some kind of liquid (blood, dew, water, etc.).